# Variadic datastructure with overloaded methods

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, overloading

I have a system with a number of message types that can be published/subscribed. When a new type is added, a large number of files have to be updated to add support for the new method type.

Is it possible to declare a C++ class with overloaded pure virtual methods as a variadic data structure?

When the C++ program below is compiled, the declaration of the 2nd publish method for type "`MessageB`" is hidden by the declaration of "`MessageA`".

> main.cpp:57:41: error: no matching function for call to ‘IPublisher::publish(MessageB)’ publisher->publish(MessageB{"world"});

This is consistent with both GCC and Clang, but Clang does emit the useful warning:

> warning: 'IPublishOne::publish' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual] virtual void publish(const T& message) = 0;

Why would method hiding occur since MessageA and MessageB are distinct types?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template <class...Ts>
struct IPublishOne;

template <class T>
struct IPublishOne<T>
{
    virtual void publish(const T& message) = 0;
};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct IPublishOne<T, Ts...> : IPublishOne<Ts...>
{
    virtual void publish(const T& message) = 0;
};

struct MessageA
{
    std::string value;
};

struct MessageB
{
    std::string value;
};

struct IPublisher : public IPublishOne<MessageA, MessageB>
{
    virtual ~IPublisher() = default;
};

struct Publisher : public IPublisher
{

    void publish(const MessageA& message) override
    {
        std::cout << message.value << std::endl;
    }

    void publish(const MessageB& message) override
    {
        std::cout << message.value << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    const std::unique_ptr<IPublisher> publisher = std::make_unique<Publisher>();

    publisher->publish(MessageA{"hello"});

    // this produces compile error
    publisher->publish(MessageB{"world"});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it does not compile, it is maybe a good idea to let us know about the error message, too, not only about the warning.

Comment: Edited for posterity to add compilation error on GCC. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would method hiding occur since MessageA and MessageB are distinct
>   types?

You lack the **final overrider**.

`IPublishOne<T, Ts...>::publish` **overrides** `IPublishOne<T>::publish` as per  [class.virtual/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.virtual#2):

> If a *virtual* member function `vf` is declared in a `class Base` and in a
>   `class Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member
>   function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification,
>   and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base​::​vf` is declared, then
>   `Derived​::​vf` is also *virtual* (whether or not it is so declared) and
>   it overrides `Base​::​vf`.

What you need is a [*final overrider*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.virtual#def:final_overrider):

Specify the *final overrider* in `struct IPublishOne<T, Ts...>`:

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct IPublishOne<T, Ts...> : IPublishOne<Ts...>
{
    using IPublishOne<Ts...>::publish;  // final overrider for
                                        // IPublishOne<T>::publish
    virtual void publish(const T& message) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that defining a `publish()` method in a class hide all the `publish()` methods inherited from the base classes.

You can solve this problem adding a `using` in `IPublishOne`

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct IPublishOne<T, Ts...> : IPublishOne<Ts...>
{
   using IPublishOne<Ts...>::publish;  // <<<-------------

    virtual void publish(const T& message) = 0;
};
```

to give visibility to the inherited `publish()`.